# Refresh UI of Tabs When Variable Changes (Toggle Flipped) Without Reloading the App

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui, tabs

With what I have right now, when the toggle `HideTabBarTitles` is pressed, it requires the app to be reloaded/refreshed. Is there a way so that it changes immediately without reloading the app?

Also, when it hides the tab bar titles, the images stay above where the text normally is. I've tried using resizable but that doesn't seem to change the outcome. Here is an example of what I want it to do when the toggle is pressed (With what I want the toggle to do on the left compared to the normal app on the right):

[image: Example from Carrot Weather]

And Here is my code with the problem of needing to reload the app for the changes to appear (and the images not being centered):

Tab View:

```
        TabView {
        SummaryView().tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "leaf.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            if GlobalVariables.HideTabBarTitles == false{
                Text("Summary")} }
            StatsView().tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "chart.bar.xaxis")
        if GlobalVariables.HideTabBarTitles == false{
                Text("Stats")
            } }
        AchievementsView().tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
            if GlobalVariables.HideTabBarTitles == false{
                Text("Achievements")
            } }
        SettingsView().tabItem { Image(systemName: "gear")
            if GlobalVariables.HideTabBarTitles == false{
                Text("Settings")
            } }}
```

HideTabBarTitles is just attached to a toggle in the SettingsView

Comment: Your code is not reproducible but you can try to force reload some view by adding `.id(HideTabBarTitles)` to it.

Comment: What is `GlobalVariables.HideTabBarTitles`?   You should use either an `ObservableObject` with an `@Published` property or an `@State`/`@Binding` - The `tabItem` always leaves the space for the label even if it isn't present.

Comment: @Paulw11 'GlobalVariables.HideTabBarTitles' is a boolean variable that is changed from a toggle in the app settings. It is in 'GlobalVariables.swift' as an '@AppStorage static var' so that I can use it in both my Settings View and Main View.

Comment: That isn't the way to share a model property. Put your model in the environment or pass it explicitly to your views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by how you are storing your setting.  You haven't show that code, but a global static var isn't the right approach.

You can pass the setting as an `@Binding` to your preferences view.

```
struct TabBarView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("showTitles") var showTitles = true
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            PageView(color: .green).tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "leaf.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                if showTitles {
                    Text("Summary")
                }
            }
            PageView(color: .red).tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "chart.bar.xaxis")
                if showTitles {
                    Text("Stats")
                }
            }
            PageView(color: .yellow).tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                if showTitles {
                    Text("Achievements")
                }
            }
            SettingsView(showTitles: self.$showTitles).tabItem { Image(systemName: "gear")
                if showTitles {
                    Text("Settings")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @Binding var showTitles: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
        Toggle("Show titles", isOn: self.$showTitles)
        }
    }
}

struct PageView: View {
    var color: Color
    var body: some View {
        color.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, there seems to be an issue with calling the View. It wants 'Binding<Bool>', which could be '(HideTabBarTitles: .constant(true))'. However, this makes it so that the toggle is always true and cannot be changed. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You can use `.constant` for your preview, but you can use the `@AppStorage` property as I have at runtime.